# Access denied if I try to control Windows 2016 service remotely

Tags: windows, windows-service, windows-server-2016

I have following script:

```
cmdkey.exe /add:COMPUTER /user:COMPUTER\user /pass:somepassword
sc \\COMPUTER stop Servicename
```

Works fine with Windows 2012 R2 but not with Windows 2016. With windows 2016 I get this error: [SC] OpenService FAILED 5: Access is denied.

User is admin. If I log to COMPUTER with User and run this command - it works.
If I run this command remotely from some domain account - it works.

Same problem with alternative command:

```
psservice \\COMPUTER -accepteula stop Servicename
```

Answer (score -1):

assuming the admin account is a local account you are probably encountering [remote UAC](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/951016/description-of-user-account-control-and-remote-restrictions-in-windows-vista).